# EmebrJS + CKEDITOR error while adding links using its dialog box

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ember-1

### Type of report

Links adding with CKEditor in chrome 78.0.3904.97  gives an  error of following 
and i have checked latest firefox also and i can reproduce this

```
link.js?t=J8Q8:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.onOk (link.js?t=J8Q8:27)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:613)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.l (ckeditor.js:10)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at button.onClick (ckeditor.js:637)
    at button.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:575)
    at button.l (ckeditor.js:10)
    at button.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at button.click (ckeditor.js:574)
    at CKEDITOR.dom.element.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:566)
```

### reproduction steps

1. enable links for CKeditor
2. click the link icon in ckeditor toolbar
3. it opens a dialog to add display name and the link
4. adding link and display name
5. click ok

#### Expected result

close the dialog box and adding the link to the ckeditor text area

#### Actual result

dialog box is not closing and console gives

```
link.js?t=J8Q8:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.onOk (link.js?t=J8Q8:27)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:613)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.l (ckeditor.js:10)
    at CKEDITOR.dialog.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at button.onClick (ckeditor.js:637)
    at button.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:575)
    at button.l (ckeditor.js:10)
    at button.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at button.click (ckeditor.js:574)
    at CKEDITOR.dom.element.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:566)
```

### Other details

- Browser: chrome 78.0.3904.97  / firefox
- OS: Mac
- CKEditor version: 4.13.0
- Installed CKEditor plugins:

Using CKEditor as Emberjs Component

**components/ckeditor.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from 'project/config/environment';

export default Ember.Component.extend( {
  allowLinks: true,

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self        = this,
        $textarea   = this.$().find( 'textarea' )[0],
        ckconfig    = {

          toolbarGroups: [

            { name: 'styles' },
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list' ] },
            { name: 'others' },
            { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'undo' ] },
            { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection' ] },
            { name: 'colors' }
          ],
          removeButtons: 'Subscript,Superscript,Cut,Copy,Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Anchor,Styles,Font,FontSize,Find,Replace,SelectAll,BGColor',
          format_tags: 'h1;p',
          removeDialogTabs: 'link:advanced;link:target',
          removePlugins: 'magicline',
          disallowedContent :  {
            '$1': {
              styles: 'color'
            }
          }

        },
        outputRules = {

          indent: false,
          breakBeforeOpen: false,
          breakAfterOpen: false,
          breakBeforeClose: false,
          breakAfterClose: false
      };

    // custom config
    if ( this.get( 'allowLinks' ) ) ckconfig.toolbarGroups.splice( 3, 0, { name: 'links' } );

    CKEDITOR.config.customConfig    = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.defaultLanguage = 'en';
    CKEDITOR.config.language        = 'en';
    CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss     = config.baseURL + 'ckeditor.css' ;
    CKEDITOR.config.height          = 420;
    CKEDITOR.config.skin            = 'bootstrapck,' + config.baseURL + 'assets/bootstrapck/';
    CKEDITOR.config.colorButton_colors = '0000FF,FFA500';
    CKEDITOR.config.colorButton_enableMore = false;

    CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function(e) {

      e.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'h1', outputRules );
      e.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p', outputRules );
      e.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'ol', outputRules );
      e.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'ul', outputRules );
      e.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'li', outputRules );
    } );

    CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function(e) {

      var dialogName       = e.data.name,
          dialogDefinition = e.data.definition;

      if ( dialogName === 'link' ) {

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function () {

            var dialog        = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent(),
                linkType      = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'linkType' ),
                anchorOptions = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'anchorOptions' ),
                emailOptions  = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'emailOptions' ),
                protocol      = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'protocol' );

            linkType.getElement().hide();
            anchorOptions.getElement().hide();
            emailOptions.getElement().hide();
            protocol.disable();
        };
      }
    } );

    Ember.run( function() {

      $textarea.value = self.get( 'value' ) || '';

      CKEDITOR.replace( $textarea, ckconfig ).on( 'change', function(e) {

        self.set( 'value', e.editor.getData() );
      } );
    } );
  }
} );
```

anyone has any idea how can I fixed it ? i have checked their github issues 
as well but unfortunately I couldn't find any thing

Comment: Possible for you to recreate the problem with this [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/t8r3g6mv/)

Comment: im using emberjs i will update that code in here

Comment: @NewToJS added the code for emberjs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error was in here

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function(e) {

      var dialogName       = e.data.name,
          dialogDefinition = e.data.definition;

      if ( dialogName === 'link' ) {

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function () {

            var dialog        = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent(),
                linkType      = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'linkType' ),
                anchorOptions = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'anchorOptions' ),
                emailOptions  = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'emailOptions' ),
                protocol      = dialog.getContentElement( 'info' , 'protocol' );

            linkType.getElement().hide();
            anchorOptions.getElement().hide();
            emailOptions.getElement().hide();
            protocol.disable();
        };
      }
    } );
```

and i have updated this with following code

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function(e) {

      var dialogName       = e.data.name,
          dialogDefinition = e.data.definition;

      if ( dialogName === 'link' ) {
        dialogDefinition.getContents('info').get('protocol')['items'].splice(2, 6);
        dialogDefinition.getContents('info').get('linkType')['items'].splice(1, 4);

        var target = e.data.definition.getContents('target');
        var options = target.get('linkTargetType').items;
        for (var i = options.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
          var label = options[i][0];
          if (!label.match(/new window/i)) {
            options.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
        var targetField = target.get( 'linkTargetType' );
        targetField['default'] = '_blank';
      }
    } );
```